# Ionic and Android Studio both failing to download https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.3-all.zip for example and crashing builds

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework, gradle, visual-studio-code

I am very new to Ionic (started this week) and I am simply trying to run the sample project provided in the ionic framework documentation to an android device. I have followed all of the steps perfectly and When the build gets to a certain point it crashes and it seems to be while trying to download a version of gradle from the gradle wrapper.

The thing is when I try an ionic run I am getting the error at this point and also in Android studio when i open up a new project it fails to download this file.

I have seen quite a few posts about this problem such as deleting the .gradle file and contents such as caches, daemons and wrapper dists but none of this seems to be working.
I have added gradle to my PATH variables although i am not quite sure why Ionic doesnt recognise I have android studio downloaded?

Here is where the build gets to:

```
You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova 
telemetry on.
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\aarogers\AppData\Local\Android\sdk (DEPRECATED)
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.3-all.zip
```

Here is the error message stack trace:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target Caused by:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

Can anyone help me out here would be greatly appreciated? is there a reason why this file wont download and stopping my builds from running?

Comment: Hi TheAlmac2 did you get any fix for this, i am also getting the same issue.

Comment: Hi @Ananta Prasad,  are you on a corporate network or have firewalls setup? I had to hotspot from my phone in order to bypass the firewalls. Once it works once in the project it will cache it and not ask again for a certain amount of time. I would try this method

Comment: it woked fine. thanks